# Illustrator: Copy appearance between documents

Tags: adobe-illustrator, appearance

I am currently making assets for an InDesign project. In order to stay consistent I wanted to copy over the shadow I created to the rest of my assets. It was then when I noticed that I do not have the slightest idea how to do that ...

Note that they are all in seperate documents / .ai files, in case that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphic Styles are the easiest method moving forward with new files.

If you have a bunch of existing files, and want to copy an appearance, you can still use Graphic Styles in perhaps an easier way.

There's no easy, automated, method to apply an appearance to a collection of files, so either way you will need to "touch" each asset file.

- Take your existing element with the shadow and drag it to the **Graphic Styles** panel.
- Now merely `Edit > Copy` the element. (You can close the file now)
- Open a different asset file
- Paste
- Delete
- Select the new asset and then click the style in the Graphic Styles Panel.

The copy/pasting places the Graphic style you want into the newly opened file, then deleting the copied asset removes the actual artwork.

This is merely a ***shortcut*** to moving a Graphic Style between files without having to use a bunch of menu tracking to load files.

---

Be aware, *grouping* the artwork and *then* applying the shadow, and *then* making the Graphic Style is the procedure I would follow. Then upon opening old assets, select and group, then apply the Style. Graphic Styles actually have 2 forms - groups and individual objects. You can't tell them apart other than how they may or may not work with an object/group. So by making everything a group first, you ensure the style will work the same with everything.

Answer (score 2):

Use graphic styles.

Then follow those steps (copy/pasted from Adobe's help : https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/graphic-styles.html)

**Import all graphic styles from another document**

1. Choose Window > Graphic Style Libraries > Other Library or select Open Graphic Style Library > Other Library from the Graphic Styles panel menu.
2. Select the file from which you want to import graphic styles, and click Open.
   The graphic styles appear in a graphic style library panel (not the Graphic Styles panel).

Comment: Is there maybe some easier way? As this seems quite tedious to do for every asset I have, not to mention that they are within my cc library, so I would first have to find the folder on my pc where they are stored ...

Comment: Not that I'm aware of... sorry